# Is there a way of making a lock-free "counter" random access iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17, atomic

I'm experimenting with the execution policies on a toy problem of evaluating a polynomial at a certain point, given its coefficients and the point of evaluation (x).

Here's my implementation:

```
class counter: public std::iterator<
        std::random_access_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
        size_t,                      // value_type
        size_t,                      // difference_type
        const size_t*,               // pointer
        size_t                       // reference
>{
    size_t num = 0;
public:
    explicit counter(size_t _num) : num(_num) {}
    counter& operator++() {num += 1; return *this;}
    counter operator++(int) {counter retval = *this; ++(*this); return retval;}
    bool operator==(counter other) const {return num == other.num;}
    bool operator!=(counter other) const {return !(*this == other);}
    counter& operator+=(size_t i) { num += i; return *this; }
    counter& operator-=(size_t i) { num -= i; return *this; }
    counter operator +(counter &other) const { return counter(num + other.num);}
    counter operator -(counter &other) const { return counter(num - other.num); }
    counter operator +(size_t i) const { return counter(num + i); }
    counter operator -(size_t i) const {return counter(num - i); }
    reference operator*() const {return num;}
};


double better_algorithm_polinomials(const vector<double> & coeffs, double x) {
    return transform_reduce(execution::par, cbegin(coeffs), end(coeffs), counter(0), 0.0, plus{}, [x](double coeff, size_t index) { return coeff * pow<double>(x, index); });
}
```

This works fine for the par policy, but for the par_unseq this fails due to race conditions.

I attempted to mitigate them using atomic_size_t, but there are some places (such as copy construction, or ++(int) operator), where I'm not atomic and probably have to use locks... I was wondering if there's a better way.

This doesn't work:

```
class counter: public std::iterator<
        std::random_access_iterator_tag,   // iterator_category
        atomic_size_t,                      // value_type
        atomic_size_t,                      // difference_type
        const atomic_size_t*,               // pointer
        atomic_size_t                       // reference
>{
    atomic_size_t num = 0;
public:
    explicit counter(size_t _num) : num(_num) {}
    counter(counter &other) {  num = other.num.load();}
    counter& operator++() {num += 1; return *this;}
    const counter operator++(int) {num += 1; return counter(num-1);}
    bool operator==(counter &other) const {return num == other.num;}
    bool operator!=(counter &other) const {return !(*this == other);}
    counter& operator+=(size_t i) { num += i; return *this; }
    counter& operator-=(size_t i) { num -= i; return *this; }
    counter operator +(counter &other) const { return counter(num + other.num);}
    difference_type operator -(counter &other) const { return num - other.num; }
    counter operator +(size_t i) const { return counter(num + i); }
    difference_type operator -(size_t i) const {return num - i; }
    size_t operator [](size_t i) const {return i;}
    reference operator*() const {return num.load();}
};
```

Comment: I struggle to see what you're getting at...

Comment: I'm trying to have some way of concurrently telling which index the transform is working on. The trivial way would be to provide a second vector filled by iota, but that seems very wasteful to me, having to allocate all that extra memory, filling it up, and then deleting it for every function call... I thought a random iterator could do the trick, but I can't make it work unsequentially. I'm looking for a fix to the iterator approach or a different approach that doesn't involve creating a whole index vector.

Answer (score 1):

> I attempted to mitigate them using atomic_size_t

Note that you should statically assert that `std::atomic<std::size_t>` is actually lock-free in your platform.

> but there are some places (such as copy construction, or ++(int) operator), where I'm not atomic and probably have to use locks...

You cannot acquire locks when using unsequenced execution policies! See [algorithms.parallel], e.g. [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-7) and [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#defns-3).

Comment: Good idea about checking atomicity, it is indeed atomic on my platform, but my iterator is still not atomic even if the underlying counter is... Is there a way to make it atomic?

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe Hm... I am trying to understand exactly the requirements at the moment. For instance, reading [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.parallel#exec-2) it would seem that an algorithm won't call unsynchronizedly a function of the iterator that would modify the iterator more than once, but I am not sure. I will ask a question about that. By the way, which compiler/stdlib are you using to test this?

Comment: Using gcc 9.1 and tbb 2019 u8. Can you think of another way of letting reduce_transform know which index it's working on, i.e. without wastefully saving the index as part of the coefficient vector \ in another vector?

Comment: @Mr.WorshipMe I guess you could create an iterator class that wraps an iterator to a `vector<double>` but returns the value plus the index in a tuple. Then you can simply use `std::reduce`, too.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting approach, but knowing which index the iterator wrapper is on seems to be the same problem I'm struggling with right now... Can you provide an example?