# Parallel for loop with std::for_each and std::views::iota

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++, c++20, std-ranges

I want to set up an easy workaround for parallelized index-based for-loops using `std::views`.

For running in sequence the code looks like this:

```
int main() {

    //pseudo-random numbers

    random_device rd;
    default_random_engine eng(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 100);

    auto r = ranges::views::iota(0, 10);
    vector<double> v(10, 1);
    for_each(r.begin(), r.end(), [&](int i) {v[i] = distr(eng); });
    for (auto&& i : v) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
}
```

This works fine. I am using the standard version of `std::for_each()`, not the one in the `ranges` namespace, because those don't have the execution policies. Now the parallel version. Only difference:

```
for_each(execution::par, r.begin(), r.end(), [&](int i) {v[i] = distr(eng); });
```

MSVC gives an error:

```
error C2338: Parallel algorithms require forward iterators or stronger
```

I found a similar issue here: [Using ranges::view::iota in parallel algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185974/using-rangesviewiota-in-parallel-algorithms) and I implemented the solution offered there:

```
    auto r = views::iota(0) | views::take(10);
    vector<double> v(10, 1);
    auto input_range = ranges::common_view(r);

    for_each(execution::par, ranges::begin(input_range), ranges::end(input_range), [&](int i) {v[i] = distr(eng); });
    for (auto&& i : v) cout << i << " "; cout << endl;
```

However, I am still facing the error

```
error C2338: Parallel algorithms require forward iterators or stronger.
```

Does someone know whether there is a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p2408 is adopted in C++23 now. In MSVC 19.34 (VS 17.4) or later, the code will compile if you turn on `/std:c++latest` (`/std:c++20` will also work). [EXAMPLE](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:26,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:26,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:26,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:26,startLineNumber:15),source:%27%23include%3Crandom%3E%0A%23include%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include%3Cranges%3E%0A%23include%3Cexecution%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%09using+namespace+std%3B%0A%0A%09random_device+rd%3B%0A%09default_random_engine+eng(rd())%3B%0A%09uniform_int_distribution%3Cint%3E+distr(0,+100)%3B%0A%0A%09auto+r+%3D+ranges::views::iota(0,+10)%3B%0A%09vector%3Cdouble%3E+v(10,+1)%3B%0A%09for_each(execution::par,r.begin(),+r.end(),+%5B%26%5D(int+i)+%7Bv%5Bi%5D+%3D+distr(eng)%3B+%7D)%3B%0A%09for+(auto%26%26+i+:+v)+cout+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+%22+%22%3B+cout+%3C%3C+endl%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_34_x64,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x64+msvc+v19.34+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: [link to p2408](https://wg21.link/p2408). A TL;DR of what p2408 would be nice.

Comment: Tried it, it works!

Comment: Is there a workaround for gcc that doesn't fully form the indices vector?

Answer (score 7):

The return type of `operator*()` of `views::iota`'s iterator is *not* a reference type but a value type, which makes it *not* a forward iterator but an input iterator in C++17. Since the C++17 parallel algorithm requires forward iterators, you cannot apply it to `views::iota`.

> Does someone know whether there is a solution to this issue?

There is already a paper [p2408r4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2408r4.html) addressing this issue, so there is *no* simple solution in the standard until it is adopted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful answer! (I would upvote if I could :) )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just a small update.
As was pointed out, the code does not compile with MSVC.
The code does, however, compile with g++-11 since libstd++ does not do any up-front checking of the iterator category.
However, the code runs always in serial, irrespective of the execution policy.

Important: The following is just my suggestion, please correct me if I am wrong.
If you still want to implement an easy parallelized index-based `for` loop, you can make use of STL containers rather than views:

```
template<typename Policy, typename func>
void parallel_for(Policy p, int first, int last, func f) {

    vector<int> idxs(last - first);
    iota(idxs.begin(), idxs.end(), first);
    for_each(p, begin(idxs), end(idxs), f);
}
```

Instead of having a view, we now just store the indices in a `vector<int>`. This of course comes with a memory and runtime overhead since memory for the container must be allocated and the container must be filled with the indices.
The function in action could look like this:

```
int fib(int i) {
    if (i <= 1)
        return i;
    return fib(i - 1) + fib(i - 2);
}

int main() {

    vector<vector<double>> mat(100, vector<double>(100, 1));

    parallel_for(execution::par, 0, mat.size(), [&mat](int i) {

        for (int j = 0; j < mat[i].size(); ++j) {
            mat[i][j] = fib(40);
        }
        });
}
```