# Parallel for_each without container

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, stl

Is there a straightforward way in modern C++ to use `std::for_each` with execution policy `std::execution::par_unseq` without a container?

I’d like to benefit from parallel execution in standard C++ way (without tbb, boost, MS-specifics, etc.) and don’t want to create a dummy container like I have to do now:

```
const int amount_of_iterations = 10;
std::vector<int> dummy(amount_of_iterations);
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, dummy.begin(), dummy.end(), [&](int& item) {
    int idx = int(&item - &(*dummy.begin()));
    foo(idx);
});
```

Is there any convenient way to do so, like “counting iterators”, “fake containers” or something like that?

**Update**
I tried the approach with std::views::iota:

```
auto r = std::ranges::views::iota(0, 10);
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq,r.begin(), r.end(), [&](int& item) {
    int idx = int(&item - &(*r.begin()));
    foo(idx);
});
```

But it doesn't work since now I can't get the address of the first element of the range to calculate the index:

```
error C2102: '&' requires l-value
```

So, now I have two questions:

1. Is my approach to get the index in the original code the best (safe, straightforward, etc.) or there is a better solution?
2. How can I get it working for the solution with the ranges?

Comment: `std::for_each`still needs to iterate over something.  So all you need to do is provide suitable iterators for your _"non-container"_

Comment: @RichardCritten, yes, this is exactly my question (in case there are no better ways), how to create "fake iterator" over nothing just for counting purposes without writing much code?

Comment: Are you limited to C++17? C++20 has `std::views::iota`, which could work here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, no, I am not limited (this is just the the only "highest version label" I found to show that I am fine with any new versions, you are correct, I will remove). How could I use `std::views::iota` for this? Could you please give a hint (or answer)?
Do you mean this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587975/parallel-for-loop-with-stdfor-each-and-stdviewsiota ?

Comment: Yes, that one..

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, unfortunately I can't find a way to calculate the index, see the update section of the question. Any clues?

Comment: Simply make the lamdba `[&](int item)`, `item` is already the index.

Comment: *"Can I get an index this simple way when I work with real containers"* No? `views::iota` pretends to be a container with consecutive integers in it, but doesn't store them anywhere. If you tried this with a real container, your lambda would just receive its elements. *"create a range like iota(0, 9) to stress that"* Seems no, but nothing stops you from writing a wrapper function.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you so much! Worked like a charm! Two questions: (1) Can I get an index this simple way when I work with real containers like vectors or should I use my formula? (2) Am I correct that there is no way to use create a range like iota(0, 9) to stress that I need elements from 0 to 9, since this is the STL agreement that the second argument should be "next to last" and the best way I can do is to write ...std::next(r.end())... in std::for_each instead of r.end() ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks again. So, I is my option to get the index for container is the best or should it be rewritten to comply with STL standard? I found a way to support itoa(0,9) format with std::next and updated my comment above. Would you like to reshape your comments to answer or you'd like me to post the answer to the original question?

Comment: I'll post an answer in a moment. *"is my option to get the index for container"* I don't understand, if you start using `iota`, you won't have a container anymore? What index do you mean? Or is this a separate question?

Comment: I mean, if `int idx = int(&item - &(*dummy.begin()));` in the first code snippet (in presence of vector container) could be improved to comply STL style and standard?

Comment: So, it's a separate question. I would do `&item - std::data(dummy)`. That would automatically break if given a non-continuous container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::views::iota` like this:

```
auto r = std::ranges::views::iota(0, 10);
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, r.begin(), r.end(), [&](int idx)
{
    foo(idx);
});
```

The lambda receives the index directly.