# C++ parallel STL Vectorized algorithm not implemented p2408

Tags: c++, gcc, tbb, std-ranges, c++23

I'm compiling the C++ code below with g++ 14.0.0:

```
g++ -I/path/to/c++/14.0.0 -L/path/to/c++/libstdc++ -ltbb -std=c++23 -o main main.cc
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <algorithm>                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <execution>                                                                                                                                                                                        
#include <ranges>                                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <thread>                                                                                                                                                                                           
#include <syncstream>                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
{                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;                                                                                                                                                                     
  auto r = std::views::iota(0) | std::views::take(10);                                                                                                                                                      
  auto input_range = std::ranges::common_view(r);                                                                                                                                                           
  std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::ranges::begin(input_range), std::ranges::end(input_range),                                                                                                  
                [&](int i) {                                                                                                                                                                                
                  std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();                                                                                                                                     
                  std::this_thread::sleep_for(2000ms);                                                                                                                                                      
                  std::osyncstream(std::cout)  << this_id << std::endl ;                                                                                                                                    
                });                                                                                                                                                                                         
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

the code compiles but I get the warning

```
In function ‘_RandomAccessIterator __pstl::__internal::__brick_unique(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _BinaryPredicate, std::true_type)’:
note: ‘#pragma message:  [Parallel STL message]: "Vectorized algorithm unimplemented, redirected to serial"’
 1219 |     _PSTL_PRAGMA_MESSAGE("Vectorized algorithm unimplemented, redirected to serial");
```

I'm configuring gcc with

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/dir --disable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-default-pie --enable-default-ssp --disable-fixincludes --with-mpfr=/path/to/mpfr --with-mpc=/path/to/mpc --with-gmp=/path/to/gmp --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go,lto,m2,objc,obj-c++ --no-create --no-recursion
```

and `config.log` has the variable `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with the correct path to MKL TBB.

I thought that p2408 was implemented as per the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587975/parallel-for-loop-with-stdfor-each-and-stdviewsiota).

Anyone knows what could I be doing wrong? TBB is installed

The code seems to have the same problem [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KsTbcr5nj).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [compiler support guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/23) on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) only MSVC version 19.34 and above supports p2408R5.

Comment: Oh no! Could I possible get a patch somewhere?

Comment: @Astor It's not very likely.  C++23 is still pretty new so compiler support should happen eventually but I would expect not until next year.  You could use a 3rd party library, or you can roll your own parallel for loop function.

Comment: Damn, that seems like a lot of work...

Comment: [OpenMP](https://www.openmp.org/) to the rescue?  There are guys on here who know a lot about it (but I don't).

Comment: Or defect to Windows...

Comment: @PaulSanders That is definitely too much :D

Comment: @Astor Coward 

Comment: The parallel STD library was based on an already implemented C++ library MSVC had if I remember correctly.  So it isn't surprising they are ahead.  They did release much of it as open source; however, vectorization is going to require compiler support.

Comment: @yakk-adamnevraumont :(

Comment: Is it possible to silence the warnings?